# How can I duplicate a line and search and replace on the duplicate with sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm trying to duplicate lines in a text file that contain certain special characters, but in the duplicate, substitute the special character with "regular" ASCII characters. The concrete use-case are accented characters.

Input:

```
éva
test
frédéric
```

Desired output:

```
éva
eva
test
frédéric
frederic
```

For now I can duplicate the lines containing the `é` character, but I'm not sure how to search and replace in the capture group.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
echo 'éva\ntest\nfrédéric' | sed 's/\(.*é.*\)/&\n\1/'
```

Can I do that with `sed`? If not, I'll be glad to work with `awk`...

Comment: What sort of output do you need if a name has *two different* characters from your special list??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can match on `é` and then apply multiple commands:

```
sed '/é/{p;s/é/e/g;}'
```

For any line containing `é`, this prints the current pattern space, then replaces all `é`s with `e` (and prints the pattern space again).

The AWK equivalent is

```
awk '/é/{print; gsub(/é/, "e")}1'
```

`sed`’s `s` command can re-use the address pattern:

```
sed '/é/{p;s//e/g;}'
```

and if your replacements are all single-character replacements, the `y` command is more efficient:

```
sed '/é/{p;y/é/e/;}'
```

Comment: I should have thought about that. Thanks for that ; I was thinking upside down

Comment: I reached to a similar answer but without the brackets, what would be the difference, or there's not any at all? (I think I know, but...)

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity the result is the same, in theory there could be a performance difference (your approach matches `é` in all lines twice).

Comment: I timed them with 10.000 lines and there's no significant difference, maybe with larger files it really does.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity yes, it’s marginal; profiling both approaches shows ~9.4% more CPU instructions in your variant (but only ~3.6% more cycles), with ~6.4% more branches and ~4.5% more branch misses on Haswell. I used `/usr/share/dict/french`, a 346,200-line file producing 454,926 lines of output.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ awk '1; gsub(/é/,"e")' file
éva
eva
test
frédéric
frederic
```

The above uses:

1. The idiomatic true condition `1` to cause awk to perform the default action of printing the current line, then:
2. `gsub()` to replace any `é`s with `e`s and if that found/replaced any `é`s then it's positive return used in the condition context again causes awk to perform the default action of printing the current (now modified) line.

Note that by using the return code from `gsub()` to tell us if any `é`s were found it saves us from redundantly having to specify the same regexp `/é/` twice in the command.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another `sed` option - inspired by [@EdMorton's `awk` answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675838/402371)

```
sed -n 'p;s/é/e/gp' file
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option, [similar to @Stephen Kitt's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675837/338177):

```bsh
$ sed '/é/p;s/é/e/g'
éva
eva
test
frédéric
frederic
```

---

- `/é/p` select the lines that have an `é` character and print.
- `s/é/e/g` print the previous lines with the substitution.